# Can any real number be expressed as an integral combination of $e$ and $\pi$?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

> Prove or disprove:
>
> For any real number $x$, there exist integers $a$ and $b$ such that $ae + b\pi=x$.

It certainly seems improbable, but how does one prove it?

Answer (score 20):

If every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ could be written as $ae+b\pi$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, then we would have a surjection from $\mathbb{Z}^2$ (which is countable) to $\mathbb{R}$ (which is uncountable).